# Comunicação entre socket e socket stream

Tags: php, windows, socket, stream

Fiz a seguinte classe:

```
class Socket {

    private $socket;
    private $loop;
    private $enviarMensagem;

    function __construct(LoopInterface $loop, $enviarMensagem) {
        $this->loop = $loop;
        $this->enviarMensagem = $enviarMensagem;
        $this->socket = stream_socket_client('tcp://172.20.50.222:4444');
        $loop->addReadStream($this->socket, array($this, 'recebeMensagem'));
    }

    public function recebeMensagem() {
        $server_response = fread($this->socket, 4096);
    }

    public function sendMessageToPainel($nomeContato, $idContato, $idMensagem, $tipoMensagem, $conteudoMensagem) {
        $response = array(
            'method' => 'onEnviarMensagem',
            'params' => array(3,
                'tempwictor',
                5,
                $nomeContato,
                $idContato,
                $idMensagem,
                $tipoMensagem,
                $conteudoMensagem,
                1)
        );
        stream_socket_sendto($this->socket, json_encode($response) . "\r\n");
    }
}
```

Funciona perfeitamente, fiz um servidor socket stream que retorna todas as mensagens que ele recebe para teste:

```
$server = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:4444", $errno, $errorMessage);
if ($server === false) {
    die("Could not bind to socket: $errorMessage");
}

$client_socks = array();
$i = 0;
while (true) {
    $read_socks = $client_socks;
    $read_socks[] = $server;
    if (!stream_select($read_socks, $write, $except, 300000)) {
        die('something went wrong while selecting');
    }
    if (in_array($server, $read_socks)) {
        $new_client = stream_socket_accept($server);
        if ($new_client) {
            echo '\nConnection accepted from ' . stream_socket_get_name($new_client, true);
            $client_socks[] = $new_client;
            echo "\nNow there are total " . count($client_socks) . " clients.n";
        }
        unset($read_socks[array_search($server, $read_socks)]);
    }
    foreach ($read_socks as $sock) {
        $data = fread($sock, 1024);
        if (!$data) {
            unset($client_socks[array_search($sock, $client_socks)]);
            @fclose($sock);
            echo "\nA client disconnected. Now there are total " . count($client_socks) . " clients.n";
            continue;
        }
        if(($i%3) == 0){
            fwrite($sock, $data . "\r\n");
            fwrite($sock, $data . "\r\n");
            fwrite($sock, $data . "\r\n");
        }
        fwrite($sock, $data . "\r\n");
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Mas este servidor é apenas para teste, preciso comunicar com um servidor que não utiliza socket stream, eu consigo enviar, mas o recebimento não é possível, já que a comunicação do outro servidor não é stream.

obs: O código deste servidor eu não tenho acesso, mas tenho outra aplicação que comunica com ele através do socket convencional.

Estou utilizando o loop do reactphp em uma api do instagram, comecei a utilizar ela só por causa desta api então sei muito pouco sobre esta ferramenta, queria continuar com ela já que a api utiliza ela para quase tudo, a única forma que eu encontrei foi utilizando o socket stream.

Encontrei isso https://github.com/reactphp/socket/blob/master/examples/13-netcat.php, fiz alguns pesquisas e descobri  que os recursos ReadableResourceStream e WritableResourceStream não funciona no windows, então abortei esta possibilidade.